# PHP Regex Remove Tag With Specific Words

Tags: php, regex

For example

```
<?php
$html = "<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Read : SOME ARTICLE</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";
?>
```

I Want to remove **`<p>Read : SOME ARTICLE</p>`**, maybe use php regex.

How to get started from `<p>Read :` **** `</p>` is gone.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried? Have a look on DOMDocument instead of Regex.

Comment: "How to get started from <p>Read : **** </p> is gone." I think this is the actual question you are asking. But I really do not get it. Could you rephrase? Give more sample input and desired output? Maybe go all the way to a [mcve].

Comment: I agree with some document but it you insist on regex: https://regex101.com/r/0VB1hi/1

Comment: @Yunnosch he wants to remove the p tag with "read" in it.

Comment: @Andreas That is your guess and I am pretty sure it is off. More likely he wants to remove tags which start with "Read", followed probably always by " :", then anything until end of the tag, instead of e.g. end of the line. I also guess that he does NOT want to remove tags with lower case "read" at the start or with "Read" in the middle of the tag. But I want that to be clarified by OP, not guessing.

Comment: Right... You want coffee with that? That is what I wrote. I did not use capital R in read or the : but I thought that was implicit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of `Regex`.

Optionally you can use `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` and `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` to avoid `html` tags.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/863645)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$html = "<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Read : SOME ARTICLE</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//p[contains(.,'Read :')]");//querying p node which contains `Read: `

$nodeToremove=$results->item(0);
$nodeToremove->parentNode->removeChild($nodeToremove);//Removing node
echo $domDocument->saveHTML();
```

Comment: DOM is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `preg_relace`

```
$html = "<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Read : SOME ARTICLE</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";

$html = preg_replace("/(<p>Read :.*?<\/p>)/", "", $html);
echo $html;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/UuUCA)

Comment: Shouldn't the `.*` Be lazy? `.*?`?